# How to tank (get threat) as a low level paladin in Neverwinter?

Tags: neverwinter

I'm running the level 12 dungeon as a level 19 paladin in Neverwinter. From [the wiki entry on threat in Neverwinter](https://neverwinter.gamepedia.com/Threat) I understand there *is* such a notion. When I queue for the dungeon it even specifically asks for a tank, a healer, and 3 dps.

However, none of my abilities say anything about threat, it seems. I have a hard time keeping mobs on me in the dungeon. I feel like I'm missing something: a *stance* of some sort, abilities, items... *anything*.

Google only leads to high/max level tanking guides, nothing aimed at beginners with low level characters.

Here's my current character sheet:

[image: paladin sheet]

And the way I've laid out the abilities:

[image: abilities task bar]

Is there anything I can do to generate more threat as a paladin "tank", especially in dungeons? Or do I have to wait until much higher level, and do the roles not mean much at early levels?